# Unwanted margin UIPopoverController

Tags: ios8, uipopovercontroller

When I present my popover in a view and place it at the side of the view. There is always a small margin, causing the popover to not stick to the side.

```
UIViewController *vc =  [self getViewController:@"popover" fromStoryboard:@"Main"];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(1100, 0, -65, 65)
                              inView:self.view
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                       animated:YES];
[vc setPreferredContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];
```

[image: Example in simulator]

How do I prevent this margin and show my popover sticking to the side of the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding my own UIPopoverBackgroundView implementation where I set my own contentview insets.

```
+ (UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10, -10, -10, -10);
}
```

and adding this backgroundview to my popovercontroller

```
[self.popover setPopoverBackgroundViewClass:[MyPopoverBackgroundView class]];
```