# Remove the left and right margins of a UIPopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I wanted to know if there was a way to remove the left and right margins of a UIPopoverPresentationController:

[image: popover]

I try with:

```
suggestionsTableViewController.popoverPresentationController?.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
```

But nothing changes.

I also try with UIPopoverBackgroundView:

```
suggestionsTableViewController.popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = HUBBPopoverBackgroundView.self
```

This is the code of my UIPopoverBackgroundView:

```
  class HUBBPopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }

  public override static func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
  }

  public override static func arrowBase() -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
  }

  public override static func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
    return 2.0
  }

  override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {
    get {
      return self.arrowOffset
    }
    set {
      self.arrowOffset = newValue
    }
  }

  override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection {
    get {
      return self.arrowDirection
    }
    set {
      self.arrowDirection = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me??

Thank you.

Comment: which margin u said

Comment: right and left, like the red lines in the picture.

Comment: its not pop over may be its an another View, ok can you show ur code which one u used red color

Comment: Hello,
Perhaps I have not explained well. The image is only to indicate the edges.
I simply have a UITableViewController that I present as UIPopoverPresentationController.
But I'd like to remove the margins if it is possible.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023234/unwanted-margin-uipopovercontroller

Comment: Yes, I have already seen this, but when I try to set the popoverBackgroundViewClass, app crash with no error. I have created a subclass UIPopoverBackgroundView and I did override contentViewInsets.

Comment: "when I try to set the popoverBackgroundViewClass, app crash" Then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I added the code of the subclass of my UIPopoverBackgroundView can you see it please? Because now the app does not crash, but remains locked and not respond to any touch.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `popoverLayoutMargins` does nothing nowadays; it used to work, but it stopped. You can dictate the *width* of a popover by using its `preferredContentSize`, but you cannot dictate its exact *placement*.

If you want that kind of control, don't use a popover; use a custom presented controller instead. Using a UIPresentationController subclass, you can take complete control of the placement of the presented view controller.

Answer (score -1):

Subclass UIPopoverBackgroundView overriding the contentViewInsets to make up for the default margins. (Note: all vars and functions of UIPopoverBackgroundView must be overridden for the subclass to work.  Configure these as needed.)

```
class NoMarginsPopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

    override var arrowOffset: CGFloat
    {
        get { return 0.0 }
        set { }
    }

    override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection
    {
        get { return [] }
        set { }
    }

    override class func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)
    }

    override class func arrowBase() -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

    override class func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

Then, assign the UIPopoverPresentationController popoverBackgroundViewClass property to the subclass.

```
popoverPresentationController?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = NoMarginsPopoverBackgroundView.self
```